# Где нужно поставить запятую?

Tags: запятые

Посмотри как хорош край в котором ты живёшь.

Comment: Чем же вам, уважаемые участники форума, помешал этот вопрос?  Слишком простым показался? А в устной речи вы сколько пауз слышите, две или одну?  Ведь  именно поэтому, как мне кажется, автор спрашивает о запятых – будьте внимательны к нашим гостям. Удивительно, но как только появляется что-то интересное,  вопрос сразу закрывают. Почему же так?

Comment: Справедливости ради скажу, что я проголосовала за "оставить открытым". Здесь есть о чем помозговать (пишут-то — кто во что горазд).

Comment: Справедливости ради, Римма,  я, конечно же,  посмотрела ваше голосование и отметила для себя,  что вы очень корректно поступили и что у вас есть свое мнение :) Пишут часто по слуху, но мы же не будем говорить,  что никогда не надо доверять слуху.

Comment: Я отменил свой голос за закрытие, но почему-то в истории это не отображается.

Comment: А я вот этого не знаю...

Comment: Скажите, а где вы смотрите голосование? Я вижу, только когда захожу на свою страницу или страницу другого участника.

Comment: Заходите в очередь проверок, открываете "Вопросы на закрытие", смотрите историю. Можно и статистику глянуть, если интересно.

Comment: Да, Римма, спасибо, что-то не сообразил. Но там только наши голоса по этому вопросу, где же еще два?

Comment: «Спрашивайте о реальной проблеме, с которой вы столкнулись. Опишите в деталях, что вы делаете и чего хотите добиться.» Это обращение Сайта к авторам, которые хотят чего-то добиться. Есть ли заслуга автора в высоком качестве задачки (будь она трижды интересна), или текста, что он тупо скопировал? Как грица, отнюдь и даже никак. Как таковой реальной проблемы не выражено. Закрывается не интересное, а вопрос, ждущий простецкой подсказки. Образчик перед вами. У любого «заинтересованного» участника форума есть возможность этот вопрос привести к условной норме, — надо ей просто воспользоваться.

Answer (score 2):

***Посмотри, /как хорош крАй, // в котором ты живЁшь.***

1. Запятые поставлены **по грамматическому принципу**. Это сложноподчиненное  предложение (СПП)  с последовательным подчинением и двумя придаточными:  (1) изъяснительным (посмотри на что?) и (2) определительным (край какой?).
2. А что у нас в устной речи, мы делим предложение на три части? Нет, оно делится **на две части** основной паузой, первая же пауза практически не обозначена. Именно это **затрудняет** пользователей в выборе знаков. Это тот частный случай, когда интонация **не соответствует** грамматике.
3. Сравнить: *Посмотри на тО, //как хорош крАй, // в котором ты живЁшь.* Здесь мы делим предложение на три части, то есть полное соответствие грамматики и пунктуации. Но почему так? Здесь влияет **структура** предложения и его **распространенность** – теперь его удобно разделить на три части.
4. Тогда вспомним про **семантику** – это третий  (и он же первый) принцип  в пунктуации.  С точки зрения семантики основное содержание передают предложения (2) и (3), а предложение (1) по значимости  как раз третье (где-то на уровне вводного слова). Можно и без «посмотри» обойтись и сказать: *Как хорош крАй, в котором ты живЁшь.*
5. Вот и получается, что **главное содержание**  в данном случае лучше передает интонация, чем грамматика.  Но у нас **два принципа**, не стоит забывать об этом!  Первая запятая ставится по грамматическому принципу.  Учитывать интонационный принцип (реальное произношение)  важно и нужно, просто  надо видеть те моменты, когда **нет соответствия** между ними.